# Can I get one key/value from a cognito sync dataset?

Tags: amazon-cognito

From AWS Lambda (Python) can I get one key/value from a Cognito Sync dataset?

My code needs the value, doesn't need to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Boto3 ListRecords](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-sync.html#CognitoSync.Client.list_records) API call to get all the records (or some records as defined by maxresults parameter).

I think you are looking for a way to mention identity id, dataset and the record's key name and get its value. This is not possible, as of now. You have to list the records and search for your relevant record.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve duplicated the data I need in dynamodb as a workaround.